# Disable submit button according to ngIf in the same angular form

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 6 and I created a reactive form. This is the form here

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="myFormSubmit()">
            <div formGroupName = "showNameGroup">  
                <label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="showName"  >
                  </label>
            </div> 
             <div *ngIf='results | async ; let items '> 
                <div *ngFor='let item of items'>
                  <div *ngIf='item.name != currentPoint.name'>
                     {{item.name}} already exists. You cannot submit until you change the name
                     <!-- also disable submit somehow -->
                  </div>                               
                </div>                  
             </div>

             <select formControlName="showType">
                <option *ngFor='let item of showTypeData' value="{{item.id}}" >{{item.name}}</option>
             </select>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `results` is updated as I type in the form's textfield

So, every time the `<div *ngIf='item.name != currentPoint.name'>` part is true I would also like to disable the submit some how. How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect the presence of the div elements, and disable the button if any of them is present in the view. To detect these elements, set a template reference variable on them:

```
<div #existingItem *ngIf="item.name !== currentPoint.name">
```

and monitor the presence of the elements with `ViewChildren` and `QueryList`. A flag can be set if at least one element is present in the view.

```
@ViewChildren("existingItem") existingItems: QueryList<ElementRef>;
public disabledButton = false;

constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Check if an element is initially present
  this.disabledButton = this.existingItems.length > 0;
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

  // Monitor the addition/removal of elements
  this.existingItems.changes.subscribe((existingItems) => {
    this.disabledButton = existingItems.length > 0;
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  });
}
```

Finally, the button is disabled if the flag is set:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="disabledButton">Submit</button>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbersh) for a demo.

Comment: Pretty neat and well-thought solution, but in my code I get a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`. The structure is much like yours, but i my case `results` change as you type in the textfield. Maybe thats it? I dont know

Comment: @slevin - I reproduced the exception and made the correction in the answer. `detectChanges` should be called also in the `QueryList.changes` callback. I modified [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbersh) to show your case.

Comment: First of all, I apologize that I did not specify that the `results` is updated as I type in the form's textfield. Ok, I will check your modifications and let you know.

Comment: It worked right away. Thanks for your help, you saved me. Keep it up

Answer (score 1):

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="myFormSubmit()">
    <div formGroupName = "showNameGroup">  
        <label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="showName"  >
        </label>
    </div> 
    <div *ngIf='results | async ; let items '> 
        <div *ngFor='let item of items'>
            <div *ngIf="!checkItem(item.name, currentPoint.name)">
                {{item.name}} already exists. You cannot submit until you change the name
                     <!-- also disable submit somehow -->
            </div>                               
        </div>                  
    </div>
    <select formControlName="showType">
        <option *ngFor='let item of showTypeData' value="{{item.id}}" >{{item.name}} </option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!check">Submit</button>
</form>
```

ts:
add the following in your ts:

```
check: boolean = true;
checkItem(item.name, currentPoint.name): boolean {
    if(item.name != currentPoint.name) {
        check = false;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        check = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good and simple, but if there are no `results` the check will never be done and the function will never be called, so the button will remain disabled, even though it should not be.

Comment: but the check variable is initialized by true, so if the function is not called the check variable won't change and the button should be enabled.

Comment: I apologize for not specifying that the `results` is refreshed as you type in the form's textfield. Here is the problem : I type in the textfield, I get data back and `checkItem` is called, the `if(item.name != currentPoint.name) {` part is true, so now the button is disabled and `check` is false. I keep typing and there are no results, so the `checkItem` is never called again and the `check` never goes back to true.